# SegFault due to invalid assignment?

Tags: c

I have an array that is declared inside a public struct like this:

```
uint16_t *registers;
```

In a function I'm retrieving a char string (stored in buffer, see code below) that contains numerical values separated by a comma (e.g., "1,12,0,136,5,76,1243"). My goal is to get each individual numerical value and store it in the array, one after another.

```
i = 0;
const char delimiter[] = ",";
char *end;

tmp.vals = strtok(buffer, delimiter);
while (tmp.vals != NULL) {
    tmp.registers[i] = strtol(tmp.vals, &end, 10);
    tmp.vals = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    i++;
}
```

The problem is that the line containing strtol is producing a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I'm pretty sure it's caused by trying to fit unsigned long values into uint16_t array slots but no matter what I try I can't get it fixed.

---

Changing the code as follows seems to have solved the problem:

```
unsigned long num = 0;
size_t size = 0;
i = 0;

size = 1;
tmp.vals = (char *)calloc(strlen(buffer) + 1, sizeof(char));
tmp.registers = (uint16_t *)calloc(size, sizeof(uint16_t));
tmp.vals = strtok(buffer, delimiter);
while (tmp.vals != NULL) {
    num = strtoul(tmp.vals, &end, 10);
    if (0 <= num && num < 65536) {
        tmp.registers = (uint16_t *)realloc(tmp.registers, size + i);
        tmp.registers[i] = (uint16_t)num;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "==> %lu is too large to fit in register[%d]\n", num, i);
    }
    tmp.vals = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how `buffer`, and `tmp` are declared and initialized, please?

Comment: Also please show us how `tmp.registers` is allocated. It's entirely possible you're also walking off the array.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [long integer is *at least* 32 bits](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/C_data_types#/Basic_types), so yes, you're going to lose information trying to shove a signed 32 bit integer into an unsigned 16 bit integer. If you have compiler warnings on (I use `-Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic`) it should tell you that.

```
test.c:20:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'uint16_t'
      (aka 'unsigned short') [-Wconversion]
        tmp.registers[i] = strtol(tmp.vals, &end, 10);
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, this isn't going to cause a segfault. You'll lose 16 bits and the change in sign will do funny things.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    long big = 1234567;
    uint16_t small = big;
    printf("big = %ld, small = %" PRIu16 "\n", big, small);
}
```

If you *know* what you're reading will fit into 16 bits, you can make things a little safer first by using `strtoul` to read an ***unsigned*** `long`, verify that it's small enough to fit, and explicitly cast it.

```
    unsigned long num = strtoul(tmp.vals, &end, 10);
    if( 0 <= num && num < 65536 ) {
        tmp.registers[i] = (uint16_t)num;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%lu is too large to fit in the register\n", num);
    }
```

---

More likely `tmp.registers` (and possibly `buffer`) weren't properly initialized and allocated points to garbage. If you simply declared the `tmp` on the stack like so:

```
Registers tmp;
```

This only allocates memory for `tmp`, not the things it points to. And it will contain garbage. `tmp.registers` will point to some random spot in memory. When you try to write to it it will segfault... eventually.

The register array needs to be allocated.

```
size_t how_many = 10;
uint16_t *registers = malloc( sizeof(uint16_t) * how_many );
Thing tmp = {
    .registers = registers,
    .vals = NULL
};
```

---

This is fine so long as your loop only ever runs `how_many` times. But you can't be sure of that when reading input. Your loop is potentially reading an infinite number of registers. If it goes over the 10 we've allocated it will again start writing into someone else's memory and segfault.

Dynamic memory is too big a topic for here, but we can at least limit the loop to the size of the array by tracking the maximum size of `registers` and how far in it is. We could do it in the loop, but it really belongs in the struct.

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t *registers;
    char *vals;
    size_t max;
    size_t size;
} Registers;
```

While we're at it, put initialization into a function so we're sure it's done reliably each time.

```
void Registers_init( Registers *registers, size_t size ) {
    registers->registers = malloc( sizeof(uint16_t) * size );
    registers->max = size;
    registers->size = 0;
}
```

And same with our bounds check.

```
void Registers_push( Registers *registers, uint16_t num ) {
    if( registers->size == registers->max ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Register has reached its limit of %zu\n", registers->max);
        exit(1);
    }
    registers->registers[ registers->size ] = (uint16_t)num;
    registers->size++;
}
```

Now we can add registers safely. Or at least it will error nicely.

```
Registers registers;
Registers_init( &registers, 10 );

tmp.vals = strtok(buffer, delimiter);
while (tmp.vals != NULL) {
    unsigned long num = strtoul(tmp.vals, &end, 10);
    if( 0 <= num && num < 65536 ) {
        Registers_push( &tmp, (uint16_t)num );
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%lu is too large to fit in the register\n", num);
    } 
    tmp.vals = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    i++;
}
```

At this point we're re-implementing a size-bound array. It's a good exercise, but for production code [use an existing library such as GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html) which provides self-growing arrays and a lot more features.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation! Indeed I simply forgot to allocate memory for tmp.registers. Please see my original posting for the new code that seems to work just fine now. I can't limit the user of my program to a predefined number of allowed numerical values so I have to increase the size of the allocated memory for tmp.registers dynamically with realloc. And no numerical value will ever be larger than 65536, so while I understand the necessity of the check ("malicious" user input, etc.), no information should be lost due to the conversion.

Comment: @ci7i2en4 Great, I'm glad you got it working! Using realloc is a good way to go. So is a linked list. As for your input, I'd suggest you do verify it. It isn't just about malicious input, but simple mistakes in the input data. If nothing else the check will save you frustrating time debugging another mysterious segfault.

Comment: I'm checking all user input with regex (before storing it in several buffers and working with them). That part of the code is just not shown here. Still a good idea from you to point it out.